# How to get parent width/height in React using Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a component and I need to get it's parent `<div>` width and height. I'm using Hooks, so all my components are functions. I've read some examples using classes, but this won't apply to my component.

So I have this component:

```
export default function PlantationMap(props) {
    <div className="stage-canvas">
        <Stage
          width={window.innerWidth * 0.5}
          height={window.innerHeight * 0.5}
          onWheel={handleWheel}
          scaleX={stage.stageScale}
          scaleY={stage.stageScale}
          x={stage.stageX}
          y={stage.stageY}
          draggable
        / >
    </div>
}
```

How could I get the `<div>` height and width to use in `<Stage width={} height={} />`?

Thank you very much in advance

Edit: I tried using the `useRef()` hook, like this:

```
const div = useRef();

return (
  <div ref={div}>
  ...
  </div>
)
```

But I can't access the `div.current` object

Comment: Why you don't use css in separate file/class and apply it here to follow separation of concerns? Its can be easier for you to mainening your code.

Comment: Because it's responsive. So I want to get the current width and height of the mounted component

Answer (score 21):

I think useCallback is what you want to use so you can get the width and height when it changes.

```
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);
  const div = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
      setWidth(node.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={div}>
    ...
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Although your approach is good, I could solve the problem using `useEffect`. The ref was trying to set the width and height before the `div` mounted, so this caused the problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh yeah! Gotcha... I got hung up on the ref with the div example and forgot the part about you passing window.xxx to Stage.

Comment: I am curious though without being able to see the Stage component, are you sure what you're trying to do can't be handled with css and media queries instead of putting the overhead of this on JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. `<Stage>` is a react-konva element that renders a canvas. I don't think I can set it using css

Comment: Gotcha... wasn't sure if it was a homemade component or not.

Comment: This approach gives me 0 back when the website is first initiated, so the answer with the resizeObserver down below did it for me

Answer (score 14):

You can make use of the built-in [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver):

```
export default function PlantationMap(props) {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

    useEffect(() => {
        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((event) => {
            // Depending on the layout, you may need to swap inlineSize with blockSize
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentBoxSize
            setWidth(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize);
            setHeight(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize);
        });

        resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById("div1"));
    });

    return (
        <div id="div1" className="stage-canvas">
            <Stage
                width={width * 0.5}
                height={height * 0.5}
                onWheel={handleWheel}
                scaleX={stage.stageScale}
                scaleY={stage.stageScale}
                x={stage.stageX}
                y={stage.stageY}
                draggable
            / >
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: very nice solution deserves the likes!

Comment: Loved this solution, just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This solution creates a new ResizeObserver every time this component is rendered. You need to add a dependency array to useEffect(). Also, you need to disconnect the ResizeObserver in the cleanup callback of the effect.

Comment: I advise not to use document.getElementById(), because if you have multiple components you will have the same id multiple times. Instead i used a ref on the parent div and then called ref.current.getElementByClassName("yourComponentClassName")[0] this is a more failsafe approach, that never reaches outside of the actual component

Answer (score 13):

Declare a reference using `useRef` hook and then read `current.offsetHeight` and `current.offsetWidth` properties.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const PlantationMap = (props) => {

    const stageCanvasRef = useRef(null);

    // useEffect will run on stageCanvasRef value assignment
    useEffect( () => {

        // The 'current' property contains info of the reference:
        // align, title, ... , width, height, etc.
        if(stageCanvasRef.current){

            let height = stageCanvasRef.current.offsetHeight;
            let width  = stageCanvasRef.current.offsetWidth;
        }

    }, [stageCanvasRef]);

    return(
        <div className = "stage-canvas" ref = {stageCanvasRef}>
            <Stage
              width={window.innerWidth * 0.5}
              height={window.innerHeight * 0.5}
              onWheel={handleWheel}
              scaleX={stage.stageScale}
              scaleY={stage.stageScale}
              x={stage.stageX}
              y={stage.stageY}
              draggable
            / >
        </div>);

}

export default PlantationMap;
```

Comment: Is this sample going to render with incorrect size at first and then immediately rerender with correct size?

Comment: On the first render, stageCanvasRef.current may be empty, so you will access the height and width on the second render (or on any rerender after it). But anyway, the sample isn't modifying the size of the element, just accessing its properties.

Comment: When I try this in my TypeScript React Native app, I get this error: `Property 'offsetWidth' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Comment: Add <any> to useRef definition, as stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475517/7417863

Comment: This approach gives me 0 back when the website is first initiated, so the answer with the resizeObserver down below did it for me

Answer (score 5):

I think ResizeObserver is the way to go as mentioned in the answer from Dan.
I just wouldn't use the `document.getElementById`. Either use `useMeasure` from [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) or create everything on your own.

There are two scenarios:

1. Component contains the container that you'd like to observe
2. Component is a child component and doesn't have the container reference

**To 1 - Reference directly accessible**

In this case, you can create the reference with `useRef` in the component and use it at `resizeObserver.observe(demoRef.current)`.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const DisplaySize = ({ width, height }) => (
  <div className="centered">
    <h1>
      {width.toFixed(0)}x{height.toFixed(0)}
    </h1>
  </div>
);

const Demo = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
  const demoRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((event) => {
      // Depending on the layout, you may need to swap inlineSize with blockSize
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentBoxSize
      setWidth(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize);
      setHeight(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize);
    });

    if (demoRef) {
      resizeObserver.observe(demoRef.current);
    }
  }, [demoRef]);

  return (
    <div ref={demoRef} className="App">
      <DisplaySize width={width} height={height} />
    </div>
  );
}; //);

export default function App() {
  return <Demo />;
}
```

**To 2 - Reference of container not directly accessible:**

This case is probably happening more often and requires slightly more code.
You need to pass the reference from the parent to the child component with `React.forwardRef`.

Demo code can be found below or in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-resizeobserver-demo-7jjt4)

Some words to the code:

- In the parent component you create a reference with `const containerRef = useRef()` and use it at the main container with `<div ref={containerRef}/>`. Under the hood it will do something like `ref => containerRef.current=ref`
- Next, pass the reference to the `Demo` component.

**Why not use `React.createRef`?**

That would work too but it would recreate the reference on every render of your App. Please have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-useref-and-createref-in-reactjs/) for an explanation of the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`.

In short, use `useRef` with functional components and use `createRef` with class-based components.

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const DisplaySize = ({ width, height }) => (
  <div className="centered">
    <h1>
      {width.toFixed(0)}x{height.toFixed(0)}
    </h1>
  </div>
);

const Demo = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(100);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((event) => {
      // Depending on the layout, you may need to swap inlineSize with blockSize
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentBoxSize
      setWidth(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize);
      setHeight(event[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize);
    });

    if (ref && ref.current) {
      resizeObserver.observe(ref.current);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return <DisplaySize width={width} height={height} />;
});

function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="App">
      <Demo ref={containerRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.centered {
  display: flex; /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column; /* make main axis vertical */
  justify-content: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
  align-items: center; /* center items horizontally, in this case */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

## Library React-use

There are also some useful hooks in `React-use` that could help here.

`useWindowSize` and `useSize` look pretty similar but after looking at the source code the first one relies on the `window.onresize` event and requires less code to implement.

`useSize` will add an iframe below the current component (`z-index: -1`) to track the size with `resize` event and requires more code. It also adds a little debounce with `setTimeout`.

So use `useWindowSize` if you just need the width/height to do some calculations on the first render and `useSize` if you'd like to show that the size changed.

### useWindowSize

If you just need to get the window size [useWindowSize](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useWindowSize.ts) is the way to go.
They're doing it with [onresize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) with `document.addEventlistener('resize', resizeHandler)` and checking `innerWidth / innerHeight`
[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-resize-with-react-use-6f2z3)

### useMeasure

To track an element size, `useMeasure` can be used. It is using `ResizeObserver` under the hood, so it's like the code above where `ref` is the reference you'd like to track:

The first element returned by `useMeasure` is the `setRef` method.
So you can do the following in your component:

```js
const [setRef, { width, height }] = useMeasure();
useEffect(() => {
    setRef(ref.current)
}, [])
```

Please have a look at the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usemeasure-to-track-element-621n8).

### useSize

If you want to track the size of a component `useSize` could be used as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useSize.md).
[Codesandbox Demo `useSize`](https://codesandbox.io/s/usesize-demo-82jhb)

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge if it is concerned with style can only be registered by:

```
<Stage style={{width:window.innerWidth * 0.5,height:width:window.innerWidth * 0.5}} />
```

Comment: The `width` and `height` props are working, however I want to change `window.innerWidth * 0.5` to the value of the parent `<div>` width and height

Comment: maybe this link can help you : https://gist.github.com/nma/33f8057e4899bdb55440a693a02c431b

Answer (score 0):

My solution using observer:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export const useGetDivDimensions = () => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ height: 0, width: 0 });

  const div_ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((event) => {
      setDimensions({
        height: event[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize,
        width: event[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize,
      });
    });

    if (div_ref?.current) resizeObserver.observe(div_ref.current);
  }, [div_ref?.current]);

  return { dimensions, div_ref };
};

// ── USAGE ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

// const { dimensions, div_ref } = useGetDivDimensions();

// <div ref={div_ref}>
//   <div style={{height: dimensions.height}} />
// </div>;

// ── DOCS ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserverEntry/contentBoxSize
```

source: https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/2bf6fa1e58d30c5977810b737c6173c0

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way: [`react-use`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use)

```
import { useMeasure } from "react-use";

const Demo = () => {
  const [ref, { x, y, width, height, top, right, bottom, left }] = useMeasure();

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div>x: {x}</div> 
      <div>y: {y}</div>
      <div>width: {width}</div>
      <div>height: {height}</div>
      <div>top: {top}</div>
      <div>right: {right}</div>
      <div>bottom: {bottom}</div>
      <div>left: {left}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMeasure.md