# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'. when use useRef hook in mui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, material-ui, react-hooks

I am using [material UI](https://material-ui.com/) to build a login and registration page, using `useRef` to return a [TextFiled](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield) ref instance, and `xxxRef.current.value` to get the input value.

I can smoothly run my project and can get the `value` correctly，but the console always reminded me that:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Here is my code snippets：

```
const accountRef = useRef();

<TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="account"
            label="Account"
            name="account"
            autoComplete="account"
            autoFocus
            defaultValue={account}
            inputRef={accountRef}
/>


const payload = {
      account: accountRef.current?.value ?? '',
      password: passwordRef.current?.value ?? '',
      nickname: nicknameRef.current?.value ?? '',
};
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`useRef` is generic if you use it with TypeScript, so you can define the referenced element type like `const ref = useRef<Type>();`

Looking into the type definitions for the `inputRef` property in MaterialUI it states:

```
/**
 * Pass a ref to the `input` element.
 */
inputRef?: React.Ref<any>;
```

So for a fix you can define your refs like:

```
const accountRef = useRef<any>();
```

But the ref is passed through the input field inside the component, better type would be:

```
const accountRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

Comment: Learned something :) similar to `useState<any>` thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Correct answer should be using correct Type (HTMLInputElement) when using useRef():

```
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  const [caretPosition, setCaretPosition] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const updateCaretPosition = () => {
    inputRef.current && setCaretPosition(inputRef.current.selectionStart);
  };
```

Answer (score 5):

Like Martin said use HTMLInputElement type and add null in useRef. Error on ref attribute inside input element is gone.

```
const input = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that there are other Types which could be added to useRef.

Some other types maybe :

- `HTMLElement`
- `HTMLFormElement`
- `number`
- `string`
- etc...

useRef is commonly used for using a reference of a HTML element but it could also be used for storing data as well.