# Property current does not exist on type never - React useRef()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, strict

I know there are quiet lot of articles and related questions out there, but I am coming to you looking for help, I am having a hard time typing a custom hook which adds an event listener to the attached window. But I am getting this error.

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work, and my library does not compile. I guess this is related to having the **strict** flag on.

The function is the following.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function usePatientContextListener(handler: Function, element = window) {
  const savedHandler = useRef<Function>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler;
  }, [handler]);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler;

    const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener;
    if (!isSupported || savedHandler) return;
    
    const listener = (event: Event) => {
       // eslint-disable-next-line no-extra-boolean-cast
       if (!!savedHandler?.current) {
        savedHandler.current(event)
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("message", listener, false);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("message", listener);
    };
  }, [element]);
}
```

Also when I pass null as default value, I get another error saying that current is a read-only property. If I remove the null, the error goes away.

```
Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.
```

I have tried everything and still the error won't go away. I appreciate if you have experienced this or can help me in any way. Last, I attach the error image

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475517/2129071

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you'll be better off with useState instead of useRef, the latter is supposed to hold a mutable object, which means you can update its properties, but the object itself is not expected to change (hence the read-only property error). useState on the other hand is used for immutable object (you replace the whole object, rather than updating its properties).

Property 'current' does not exist on type 'never'.

This just means that your condition (`!!savedHandler?.current`) will never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `React.useRef` hook. Your code has something wrong. The `savedHandler` ref will be a `React.MutableRefObject` which always exists. But you `return` if it exists, this will make the TS infer the `ref` has a `never` type.

Change:

```
if (!isSupported || savedHandler) return;
```

To:

```
if (!isSupported) return;
```

For example:

```
function main() {

  const ref = { current: null }
  if (ref) return;

  // TS infer ref has `never` type
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYzACgJSIN4BQBiiECAzlIgE4CmwiAvPqSNXWFAFyJggA2-RAF9iiGA0x1guOlDZgA3ERITEU+gDoIbDlFyESJadt21OY0aIJA)

---

The complete code:

```
function usePatientContextListener(handler: Function, element = window) {
    const savedHandler = useRef<Function | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        savedHandler.current = handler;
    }, [handler]);

    useEffect(() => {
        savedHandler.current = handler;

        const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener;
        if (!isSupported) return;

        const listener = (event: Event) => {
            if (savedHandler?.current) {
                savedHandler.current(event);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('message', listener, false);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('message', listener);
        };
    }, [element]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I'm seeing the proble is mostly in the ref definition part.
Since you're defining the ref like this:

```js
const savedHandler = useRef<Function>(null);
```

there come your two issues. Since you're defining your initial value in the ref as `null`, but describing it as a Function, you're actually saying that:

1. That "function" will `never` return anything ( here's the never issue).
2. Describing a value only as Function but giving it `null` value causes this ref to be an immutable object, so you can't change it later.
3. From the combination of these two first points comes that the return type will stay `never` in every case.

In order to solve this I would suggest a slight change in the description of the ref; try to do like this:

```js
const savedHandler = useRef<Function | null>(null);
```

Check also this link, if maybe can help you: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-cannot-assign-to-current-because-read-only-property

Hope this helps