# Typescript: React Native useRef giving error "Object is possibly null"

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I'm using a ref on a View. Typescript is giving me an error "Object is possibly 'null'". What is the correct typing for a ref used on a View? Specifically I'm using an `Animated.View` but I don't think that makes a difference.

Other answers on here are for ReactJS(web) and use `const overlayEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);` but I'm looking for an answer for React Native.

```js
const Component = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    console.log(ref.current.clientHeight); 
    // ^ Error: "Object is possibly null" on the `ref.current` portion
  },[]);

  return (
    <Animated.View ref={ref} style={{height: 100}}></Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Things I tried:

```js
const ref = React.useRef<React.FunctionComponent>(null);
const ref = React.useRef<React.ReactElement>(null);
const ref = React.useRef<React.MutableRefObject<null>>(null);
const ref = React.useRef(null) as React.MutableRefObject<null>;
console.log(ref?.current?.clientHeight); 
// ^ Error: Property clientHeight does not exist on type 'never'
```

The only thing that works is this, but this isn't really a proper fix

```js
  React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    const current = ref?.current || { clientHeight: 0 }; 
    console.log(ref.current.clientHeight);
  },[]);
```

Comment: *The only thing that works is this, but this isn't really a proper fix* What do you consider to be a proper fix?

Comment: If there's a way to resolve it by setting the type correctly in the useRef declaration then to me, that's the proper fix. I assume I simply don't know what the proper typing is. If there isn't a typing to resolve it, then I guess what I wrote above is the proper fix.

Comment: Well `useRef(null)` effectively returns a ref which has a `null` current property, TypeScript warns you about it before you execute the code so you have to adapt it with a null check or an optional chaining operator just like you did

Comment: I see. And putting `useRef()` without the null makes no difference right since it's still undefined. I can accept your comment as the answer if you respond with that. Thanks

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` runs before render so that's why your ref is null. Is there any reason to use `React.useLayoutEffect` instead of `React.useEffect`

Comment: @JigneshPatel I still get the same error that `Object is possibly null` when changing it to useEffect. But I do it because I need to get the height for a height animation

Comment: @wongz are you sure that `clientHeight` exists in React Native? I may be wrong but I think this property is exclusive to the web

Comment: @GuerricP I haven't read anywhere saying that it's exclusive to web only after searching. Also, useRef is imported from React as in `React.useRef()` and not react-native so unless explicitly linked to some docs stating the contrary, I'm 99% pretty sure it's not exclusive to web only

Comment: But the `ref` is of type `Animated.View`. I don't think it has a `clientHeight` property

Answer (score 2):

Here is how `useRef` is being typed in React:

```
function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;

interface MutableRefObject<T> {
    current: T;
}
```

That means once the `MutableRefObject` is being typed, it always keeps its type so you have to type it properly with the angle brackets:

```
const ref = React.useRef<React.ElementRef<typeof View> | null>(null);
```

Comment: After changing it to a View and defining the ref as you stated, It still errors with "Property clientHeight does not exist on property View". I guess I just need to define it explicitly as you noted in the comments. Alternatively, what also makes it go away, is `const ref= React.useRef<any>(null);` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475289/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-never-when-use-useref-hook-in-mui) but some may question how proper that is. I'm okay to accept that at this stage given everything else we discussed

Comment: This is why I asked you if `clientHeight` existed in React Native because I think it doesn't. You can stick with the `any` solution but you have to be aware that the `any` type is a workaround, it just completely disables TypeScript's type checkings, just like you were writing plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its really a TypeScript issue, but more of an initialization problem. When you try to access your ref you do so in the way you would access an object and its null and not an object and thus throws the error you get.
You could either verify the ref isnt null, or initialize it to some object so that you can properly query its properties:

```js
// this
const ref = React.useRef({});



// or this
const ref = React.useRef(null);
React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
    if(ref.current !== null){
       //do stuff
    }
  },[]);
```

Comment: This makes sense. but when I put it inside `if ( ref.current !== null ) {...}` then I get the error: "Property 'clientHeight' does not exist on type never"