# upload File in React / Typescript -> Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button

i am trying to upload a file in React / Typescript.

```
const CSVImport = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const inputFile = useRef(null);

  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted file input element
    inputFile.current && inputFile.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onButtonClick}>import CSV</Button>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        ref={inputFile}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Problem is, that there is something wrong with inputFile.current.click()  -> this is the error:

```
Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

where do i need to set types?

thank you so much!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'. when use useRef hook in mui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475289/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-never-when-use-useref-hook-in-mui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can pass a type to `useRef`:

```js
const inputFile = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147937/property-does-not-exist-on-type-never) explaining as to why there is an error.

You should define the referenced element type. Since you are using `input`, pass **HTMLInputElement** type in your `useRef`. Like this `const inputFile = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);`.